# Best class for precision

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a beginner and I'm having issues with MR when trying to read values of the form 99.99.

I'm reading up as much as I can. I wanted to try to use Java's types to determine whether to use a DoubleWritable or FloatWritable, but after some research, Java seems to recommend against using either of these (double and float) for representing currency, and using BigDecimal instead.  I wasn't able to find a BigDecimalWritable in any of the Hadoop API documentation (but found something for Hive).

I'm using the FileInputFormat class which I understand defaults to a LongWritable,Text  pair.

What Hadoop data type should I use with my Driver section/Job class to work with currency?

I've tried FloatWritable and DoubleWritable and my output always ends up as String,Number.0 in the output file ("something[tab]55.0", for example, when I know 55.0 is wrong).

Comment: Did BigDecimalWritable work?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, but also refuse to concede that I need to use something from Hive for a task that seems it should be common. I may have found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) has a [BigDecimalWritable](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.0/ds_Hive/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/io/BigDecimalWritable.html). It implements [org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) so it's designed to work with Hadoop.

Comment: Right, but what if I don't want to use Hive and want to figure this out using MapReduce alone?  I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: I think you can just use the Hive BigDecimalWritable and do everything else the Hadoop way because it implements org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable.